# Pattern matching HTTPoison.Response

Tags: elixir

I'm trying handle the response from an API call using HTTPoison

In my app context I have

```rb
def add_to_cart(data, user) do
  case HTTPoison.post!(
      "https://api.moltin.com/v2/carts/" <> user <> 
      "/items", data,
      [{"Authorization",
        "Bearer #{Agent.get(:token, fn state -> state end)}"},
       {"Content-Type", "application/json"}] do

    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 201, body: body}} ->
      case Poison.decode(body) do
        {:ok, decoded} -> decoded
        {:error, error} -> {:error, error}
      end

    {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 404}} ->
      IO.puts "Not found :("

    {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
      IO.inspect reason

  end
end
```

The error I return is:

```rb
CaseClauseError at POST /order
no case clause matching: %HTTPoison.Response{response content}
```

I have used this pattern elsewhere in my code and it matches fine but when I place it here, it doesn't seem to work.

I'm sure this isn't enough information with which to work but I'm not sure at this point what else to put.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: This was basically a typo, i.e. `case HTTPoison.post!(` should have been `case HTTPoison.post(`, i.e. without the `!` after `post`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Elixir convention is: banged versions of functions—instead of `{:ok, result}` and `{:error, reason}`—return `result` on success and raise on error. [Grep this page](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/try-catch-and-rescue.html) for “Elixir doesn’t impose exceptions” for the reference.

`HTTPoison` [follows this convention](https://github.com/edgurgel/httpoison/blob/master/lib/httpoison/base.ex#L188-L194).

To make your code work, one should either use `HTTPoison.post` (**not** banged) in the very top case, or match the result respectively:

```
try
  %HTTPoison.Response{status: status, body: body} =
    HTTPoison.post!(...)
  case status do
    201 -> ...
    404 -> ...
  end
rescue
  e in HTTPoison.Error ->
    IO.inspect e
end
```

Comment: try / catch smells like OO approach - I would stick to pattern matching here ;)

Comment: @Kociamber mostly true, but the purpose of any answer is to unveil all the possibilities; sometimes it makes sense to omit the whole rescue clause to let it crash soon. Sometimes it makes sense to rescue (imagine a chain of subsequent calls and if any fails, we want to log and retry—this is doable with `with` special form, but still...)

Comment: It's quite easy to track "fail path" of chained function calls without try statement and indeed - `with` is a great tool for that :)

Comment: Removing the ! was what put me on the path to fixing my problem.  Tired eyes were not seeing what, in retrospect, seems obvious.  Thanks everyone for your help!

Answer (score 3):

What about a nice and classy pattern matching suggested by HTTPoison docs? Just get rid of exclamation mark and try something like this:

```
case HTTPoison.post(stuff) do
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 200, body: body}} ->
    decoded_stuff = Poison.decode(body) # use another nice case statement here
  {:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 404}} ->
    IO.puts "Not found :("
  {:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} ->
    IO.inspect reason
end
```

Answer (score 1):

According to that error message you don't need the `:ok` and `:error` atoms in your tuples, try changing them from:

```
{:ok, %HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 201, body: body}} -> #...
{:error, %HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason}} -> #...
```

To:

```
%HTTPoison.Response{status_code: 201, body: body} -> #...
%HTTPoison.Error{reason: reason} -> #...
```

---

I think in other places in your app you are probably using `post/4` instead of `post!/4`, `post/4` (without the `!`) returns the tuple with the `:ok` atom, while post `post!/4` (with the `!`) kind of assumes that everything will work, doesn't return an atom in the tuple, and will throw an exception if something goes wrong.